# CF7 Rest Api Post issues

Tags: wordpress, postman, contact-form-7, wordpress-rest-api, headless

i have a React headless website based on Wordpress. I need to reach CF7 Rest Api, so i can use it to send email. While i was testing api post request with postman i encountered an error, returning me message that 'No route was found matching the URL and request method'.

In postman i tested path, so i tried to make a POST request to this url

https://test.test/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/56c1e89/feedback

and request body:

```
{
  "your-name": "test",
  "your-email": "test@test.it",
  "your-message": "test message"
}
```

I got this error from postman

```
{
  "code": "rest_no_route",
  "message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method.",
  "data": {
    "status": 404
  }
}
```

I used POST method, no Auth (i tried even with Application Password but without success), form id from cf7 is correct ( i even changed form and form id), the url is a standard cf7 url and the first part is correct, i use laragon as dev env (but i tried even with real website scenario so i think it doesn't mind), all form fields match cf7 form field.

What i'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Wrong form ID: `https://test.test/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/56c1e89/feedback` here `56c1e89` is the html id attribute applied to your rendered form, while rest apis want you to pass the "postID" of your contact form (which is a positive integer number - base10)

Comment: Are you using Nginx or Apache inside Laragon?

Comment: I'm using Nginx but i tried with real server too and same problem. Thanks

Comment: @GrafiCode thanks. with postID the response changed  `{
  "code": "wpcf7_unsupported_media_type",
  "message": "The request payload format is not supported.",
  "data": {
    "status": 415
  }
}`  . i really use a simple cf7 form without any media attached. Do you know what can be the issue about it? Thanks

Comment: are you setting `content-type` as `multipart/form-data`? cf7 controller requires that

Comment: Yes i even tried with that content-type but response is this `<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
{"contact_form_id":350,"status":"mail_sent","message":"Thank you for your message. It has been sent.","posted_data_hash":"dae2c174532e1d7bf28e36306dc2fd98","into":"#","invalid_fields":[]}`